# Node.js middleware does not work properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have a module with Routes in it. I want to check the access before letting user move forward. In Routes module I have two routes and two access-check functions, that I'd like to use as middlewares:

```js
const doesUserExist = (req, res, next) => {
    if (!users[req.params.id]) {
        res.send(`Такого пользователя не существует`);
        return;
    }
    next();
}

const doesCatExist = (req, res, next) => {
    if (!cats[req.params.id]) {
        res.send(`Такой кошечки не существует`);
        return;
    }
    next();
}

dbAccess.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { name, age } = users[req.params.id];
    res.send(`Пользователь ${name}, ${age} лет`);
});

dbAccess.get('/cats/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { nickName, color } = cats[req.params.id];
    res.send(`Кошечка ${nickName}, ${color} цвет`);
});
```

Then I export these middlewares into main file and use them the following way:

```js
app.use('/users/:id', doesUserExist);
app.use('/', dbAccess);

app.use('/cats/:id', doesCatExist);
app.use('/', dbAccess);
```

For no reason to me, only first middleware works. If I try to enter the id of cat that does not exist, I get an error `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'nickName' of 'cats[req.params.id]' as it is undefined.`, so second middleware does not working at all and no access-check happens. I created another Routes module with another route and middleware in it and used it in Main file too and it **works**:

```js
app.use('/users/:id', doesUserExist);
app.use('/', dbAccess);

app.use('/cats/:id', doesCatExist);
app.use('/', dbAccess);

app.use('/testpage', doesHaveAccess);
app.use('/testpage', testPage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A request `GET /cats/1`

- ignores the route `app.use('/users/:id', doesUserExist)`, because the path does not match
- takes the route `app.use('/', dbAccess)`, because `/` matches every path
- inside `dbAccess`

  - it ignores `dbAccess.get('/users/:id', ...)`, because the path does not match
  - it takes `dbAccess.get('/cats/:id', ...)`, because the path matches. This then leads to the error you observed, because `cats[req.params.id] === undefined`.
- The route `app.use('/cats/:id', doesCatExist)` is never reached by that request.

You should write

```js
app.use('/users/:id', doesUserExist);
app.use('/cats/:id', doesCatExist);
app.use('/', dbAccess);
```

Comment: I understood your algorythm. Thank you for explanation. But your decision does not work properly. If you try to enter invalid ID, it's ok, you get to `doesUserExist` middleware and see message that user does not exist, but if you enter valid ID, you recieve `Cannot /GET /users/1` I don't understand why is it happens.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that `dbAccess` is a router, not a middleware. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Now it works as it should! Thank you!